# how to parse class file format

Tags: java, class

Does anybody know some opensource project could parse .class file format? Without source code, I could unzip the JAR file, and I try to get the class name, function name or some strings something like that contains in the class file, is that possible?

Comment: Well there's the `jar` tool... what do you need which *isn't* covered by using `jar` and then `javap`?

Comment: The "tool" is known as Java.  Particularly the classes in java.zip.  See [here](http://www.zlib.net/) for the file format (other than the manifest, which is documented elsewhere).  However, parsing the .class files contained therein is an entirely different problem.

Comment: I guess javap is not helpful as I just have the JAR file, not have the source code.

Comment: javap doesn't need source. It works on class files.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if there are some open source project like smali which parse dex file to assembly code. But for java .class file format.

Comment: Would you like to decompile the code? do you know there's tools for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [JarInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) For the actual .class file you can use [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/)

Comment: Thansk for help. Maybe I am wrong, JarInputStream didn't have the methods to parse information inside the .class file.

Comment: @user1150246 - Then you asked the wrong question.

Comment: added ASM and BCEL as reference.

Comment: I guess BECL is what I need, I will check it later, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to inspect a jar at coding time then, as suggested by Jon Skeet and Tom Anderson in the comments, `javap` will take a .class file and extract the function names and such.

If you need a solution to work at run time, then you could use a combination of a jar/zip file reader and Java's inbuilt reflection capabilities as shown in [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html). This would let you find/construct the fully qualified names of any classes from the jar and then programatically pull information from them.

Comment: It should be noted that if you use reflection you must "load" the class first, and it then becomes "attached" to your application.  This may be exactly what you want (if, eg, doing a roll-your-own "bean" system), or it may be bad.  To avoid this "attachment" you can use a "user class loader", allowing the loaded class to be "garbage collected" when you're done examining it, but that requires a certain amount of care.  Otherwise, you can use a package that parses the .class file without loading it.

Comment: @HotLicks admittedly the reflection approach is most suited for inspecting a class you intend to subsequently use.